# A simple recursion problem to simulate the spread of a computer virus

Tags: c++, recursion, simulation

The problem I try to solve is:

- A kind of computer virus will infect 100 computers at day 0.
- Each of the 70% of the infected computer will infect one more computer.
- There are 2 computer scientists fix the problem. Each of them can fix 1 Computer at day 1.
- Each of the subsequent days, because of their increased experience, they can fix double so many computers as the previous day.
- So, how many computers are still infected n days later ?
  And how would the figures be from the day 0 to day 20?

To solve it,  I wrote the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int computervirus(int n){ //n:Tage
    int nr_virus= 100;
    int nr_fixed;
    int rest = 0;
    if(n == 0) return 100;

    if(n <= 20){ 
        nr_virus += computervirus(n-1)*0.7;
        nr_fixed = pow(2,n);
        rest = nr_virus - nr_fixed;
    }

    return rest;

}

int main(){

    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0; i <= 20; i++){ 

        cout << "at the "<< i << " .day are still "<< computervirus(i) << " infected Computers\n" <<endl;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the number(infected computers) are just not right, because the infecting speed is definitly faster als the repair at least first 9 days.
I'm not sure where the prrblem is. Can you help?

Comment: The body of the `for` loop consists of a single statement, `cout << endl`. Then the other `cout` statement is executed once. I suggest you consult your favorite C++ textbook on the use of braces.

Comment: You have infinite recursion in your function. For any input parameter bigger than 0 you'll get Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks you r right, i just changed the if-condition, but the numbers seem like still not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion for day n try to use 70% of the result of day n+1.  This causes an infinite recursion.  You must use 70% of day-1 and it will work.  Now it's not 70% of the previous day, but it's 70% more so not `* 0,7` but `* 1,7`.

And you need to take into account that there can't be a negative number of computer infected.

Finally, you overestimate the repairs:  on day 1 it's 2, on day 2 it's 4, but as the 2 of day 1 were already counted in your recursion for day-1, so you deduce them twice.  So you should only count the aditional computers fixed the day n.  So pow(2, n-1).

The corrected code would look like:

```
int computervirus(int n){ //n:Tage
    int nr_virus= 100;
    int nr_fixed = 0;
    int rest = 0;

    if(n>0){ 
        nr_virus = computervirus(n-1)*1.7;  // n-1 not n+1
        if (n==1) 
            nr_fixed = 2;
        else nr_fixed = pow(2,n-1); 
    }
    rest = nr_virus - nr_fixed;
    if (rest<0) 
        rest = 0;
    return rest;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/qh2E0n)

Comment: thanks for ur advice, but the numbers are actually not right. every new day would 70% more computers infected as the last day, and infecting speed ist much faster as the repair.

Comment: @cchi True!  In fact there were two additional errors.  70% viruses MORE than the previous day is not the same than 70% of the previous day.  And you were overoptimistic for the removal.  I've corrected the two issues above.

Comment: By the way,  the repaired computer increases quicker than the number of infections.  It's just that the infection has a big advance.  After day 22, everything is back to normal.  But the 2 engineers would have to repair an unusual high number of computers per second, which shows that your model doesn't take into consideration further constraints.  Here a variant, using two recursive functions and no magical numbers: https://ideone.com/TVRmXD

Comment: hii @christophe , thanks for the update. I tested your code yesterday, the version like 11 hours ago and it seems already great enough. I tested your updated code just now and find this code has actually the same output(for the infection) like the last one, this one has more details. Thank you so much for your input. I 'm not sure what means the line 27(nr_fixed -= repaired (n-1);) and 29 (rest = max(nr_virus - nr_fixed, 0);)   can you please explain shortly? yes the 2 engineers would have to repair the really high number of computers per second is not been taken into consideration this time

Comment: @cchi Thank you for this positive feedback: glad to see that it helped. Here additional explanations `a -= b` is a shortcut for `a = a-b` .  And `max(a,b)` returns the biggest number of the two: so `max(a,0)` is the same than adding `if(a<0) a=0;` after the calculation of `a`, which I did in the first version here above.

Comment: now i unterstand what line 29 means. at the line 27 i mean why should we minus the repaired(n-1) ?  i just tested this line regarded as a comment, the result is better without this line maybe? because everyday the number of infection should at first minus the at that day repaired numbers, before the infection*1,7 for the next day. i also wrote down all the results on the paper and think this kind of situation is better.  with line 27 comes for example at day 20 still 662699 infection but 1048576 repaired, that means actually no infected computer anymore. is my assume meaningful?

Comment: @cchi yes !that's it!

Comment: Note that `pow()` works with floating-point numbers, so it could be inaccurate. It's better to use bit-shifting for powers of two.

Comment: @FeiXiang yes indeed, it's a possibility. But I'm not sure that OP knows how it works yet. In addition, most floating point encodings reliably represent powers of 2 maths (since their internal representation is based on power of 2 fractions and exponents).  Anyway, it would not make the final result much more accurate since it also depends on an 1.7 factor for which there's no int shortcut. Finally, I'd preferred to keep FP maths, since it's a modelling problem, and it should be easy to adapt the progression factors (e.g. what results with virus spread of 1.4241 and experience gain of 1.9)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use braces around the body of your for loop

```
int main(){

    for(int i=0; i <= 20; i++)
    { 
        cout << endl;
        cout << "at the "<< i << " .day are still "<< computervirus(i) << " infected Computers\n" <<endl;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Put a left brace `{` before the first statement in your loop, and a right brace `}` after the last.

Because the braces were missing only the first statement `cout << endl;` was inside the loop.

Comment: thanks, but the problem still exist.. the results from 0. day to 20. day should be putted out, but it still has the result from 0. day

Comment: @cchi I ran the program I got 20 days of output. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: i also got 20 days of output now after update (i already edited the code), but the problem now is that the number of infected computer (rest of output) ist not right

Comment: @cchi Well that's a different problem which I didn't claim to solve. You should ask a new question with the latest code.

Comment: @cchi I guess you didn't understand what I said, you should ask a **new** question with the latest code. This site isn't a chat room, it's meant to create a repository of searchable questions and answers, that doesn't work if you keep editing the same question.